# Write to CSV file using CsvHelper in C#

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I tried to write to CSV file using CsvHelper in C#.
This is the link to the library http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/
Nothing is sent to the csv file. I tried doing "`exportCsv.WriteField("Hello");`" but still nothing happened.

```
List<string> ColumnOne = new List<string>();
List<string> ColumnTwo = new List<string>();
var csvTextWriter = new 
    StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\ExportTest.csv");
var exportCsv = new CsvWriter(csvTextWriter);
    //creating a list to store workflows then adding name and description to the myWorkflowsList list
   if (myWorkflows.WorkFlowCollection.Any())
   {
        foreach (var Workflow in myWorkflows.WorkFlowCollection)
        {
                    ColumnOne.Add(Workflow.WorkflowName);
                    ColumnTwo.Add(Workflow.WorkflowDescription);
        }
        exportCsv.WriteField(ColumnOne);
        //exportCsv.WriteField(ColumnTwo);
        exportCsv.NextRecord();
        exportCsv.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine("File is saved: 
                C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\ExportTest.csv");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any call that *writes* any records. No `WriteRecords` or `WriteRecord`. Only a weird call to `WriteField` that tries to add an an entire list of strings into a single cell

Comment: I want the output to be full of "workflow names" in column 1 and "workflow description" in collumn 2. so how do you recommend i use records?

Comment: Did you read CsvHelper's documentation site? It shows how to write records *and* how to write custom headers. Your code doesn't add any records

Comment: I did. but adding records in my case would not work

Comment: It works. *Not* adding records though is guaranteed to not write results.

Comment: Paired arrays/lists like that are an anti-pattern. _Don't do that_. Instead of two lists, using a small class (or even use a Tuple) with **one** list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't add any records. It doesn't have any calls to `WriteRecords` or `WriteRecord`. It looks like it's trying to write an entire list of strings into a single field instead.

To write two columns out to a file you can use `WriteRecords, eg :

```
var data = from flow in myWorkflows.WorkFlowCollection
           select new { flow.WorkflowName,flow.WorkflowDescription};
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("test.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(data);
}
```

This will write a file with field names `WorkflowName` and `WorkflowDescription`

You can change how the fields are written by creating a small class that accepts only the fields you want and sets names etc through attributes :

```
class Flow
{

    [NameAttribute("Workflow Name")]
    public string WorkflowName { get; set; }
    [NameAttribute("Workflow Description")]
    public string WorkflowDescription { get; set; }

    public Flow(string workflowName, string workflowDescription)
    {
        WorkflowName = workflowName;
        WorkflowDescription = workflowDescription;
    }
}


//...
var data = from flow in myWorkflows.WorkFlowCollection
           select new Flow(flow.WorkflowName,flow.WorkflowDescription);
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("test.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(data);
}
```